# Find if a PostgreSQL database exists with bash

Tags: bash, postgresql, postgresql-10

I have a bash function where I check if a PostgreSQL database already exists.

I capture the output. If database exist PostgreSQL returns the database name as response.

```
function is_database() {
    local database=$1
    local output=$(sudo -u postgres psql -c "SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE datname=\"$database\";")
    if [[ $output = *"${1}"* ]]
    then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

is_database test
```

I get the following error:

```
column "test" does not exist
```

I am not searching for a table, but a database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use single quotes for string literals:

```bash
sudo -u postgres psql \
    -c "SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE datname='$database'"
```

Your code as it is won't work for database names like `has   spaces` or `has'quotes`.

Comment: similar `sudo -u postgres psql -c "SELECT version();" $dbname` : actually try to connect to the DB, and check `$?` afterwards in the shell

Comment: You can go one further and use the `--tuples-only` option to have psql return just the database name or nothing and not any other dross (like the table header and the footer).

Comment: Maybe this is because of my version of `psql` but this command gives me several `psql: warning: extra command-line argument "..." ignored`, I replaced it with: `echo "SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE datname='$database'" | psql -XtA -U postgres` and it worked (`-XtA` to get only database name as output, empty if not found then).